# Search non all numeric filenames in SQL with regex and replace result with value from column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I don't know if it's possible, but I am looking for a way in a Mysql database:

- search for items, where `model = 'YES-OK'` and `image` file name is not all numeric (in the example: row id 5)
  For this I found out that Regex `\/my\/dir-ectory\/\b.*[a-zA-Z]+.*\b.jpg` should work.

[image]

- Rows that are matched: replace image filename with SKU without comma.

Example database input:

```
+----+--------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id |  sku   | model  |            image            |
+----+--------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | 123,45 | YES-OK | /my/dir-ectory/abc4.jpg     |
|  2 | 123,46 | YES-OK | /my/dir-ectory/4abc.jpg     |
|  3 | 123,47 | YES-OK | /my/dir-ectory/abcd.jpg     |
|  4 | 123,48 | YES-OK | /my/dir-ectory/3a-baaac.jpg |
|  5 | 123,49 | YES-OK | /my/dir-ectory/12349.jpg    |
+----+--------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

Example output:

```
+----+--------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id |  sku   | model  |            image            |
+----+--------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | 123,45 | YES-OK | /my/dir-ectory/12345.jpg    |
|  2 | 123,46 | YES-OK | /my/dir-ectory/12346.jpg    |
|  3 | 123,47 | YES-OK | /my/dir-ectory/12347.jpg    |
|  4 | 123,48 | YES-OK | /my/dir-ectory/12348.jpg    |
|  5 | 123,49 | YES-OK | /my/dir-ectory/12349.jpg    |
+----+--------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

Is this possible in pure SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your image path has the same format in all rows:

```
select id, sku, model,
       concat(substring_index(image, '/', 3), '/', replace(sku, ',', ''), '.jpg')
from t
where model = 'YES-OK';
```

And then you can add the regular expression that you have found for the numbers.  I find it a little hard to follow.

You can easily incorporate the same logic into an `update` if you want an `update`.

Comment: Nice! It just missing the regex logic, where only non-all-numeric file name rows should be modified/selected: abc4.jpg, ab-c3.jpg, abc.jpg etc. everything except 123.jpg.